# Is it possible to save a file from test_step() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to implement MNIST digits using PyTorch Lightning.

The `train` function is like the below one

```
def train(epochs, train_loader, test_loader, model):
        early_stopping = EarlyStopping('train_loss', mode='min', patience=5)
        model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(dirpath=model_path/'mnist_{epoch}-{train_loss:.2f}',monitor='train_loss', mode='min', save_top_k=3)
        trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=epochs, profiler=False, callbacks = [model_checkpoint],default_root_dir=model_path) 
        trainer.fit(model, train_dataloader=train_loader)
        trainer.test(test_dataloaders=test_loader, ckpt_path=None)
```

The `test_step` function is like the below one

```
def test_step(self, test_batch):
    x, y = test_batch
    logits = self.forward(x)
    loss = self.mean_squared_error_loss(logits.squeeze(-1), y.float())

    # I want to calculate R2, MAPE, etc and want to save in a pandas df and 
    # need to return to the train function

    self.log('test_loss', loss)
    return {'test_loss': loss}
```

I can do calculate `R2, MAPE`, etc using `TorchMetrics`. But, I am not sure how (or is it possible) to save them in a pandas df (or maybe in a list) for the whole test dataset. I have gone through this [post](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/3705) but not sure how should I try!

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: In your `test_step()` you can return the metrics you want as a dictionary (or a list) (eg: `{'test_loss': loss, 'R2': r2_metric}`. Then you should define a method called `test_epoch_end(self, outputs)`, where `outputs` will be a dictionary containing all the elements you've returned in your `test_step()`.

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi thank you, nice idea. At, `test_epoch_end(self, outputs)` I can try to convert the dictionary into df and then how can I return a df to the `train` function's (anywhere)?

Comment: So do you have an alternating training and testing phase in each epoch?

Comment: I didn't get you. What do you mean by 'an alternating training and testing phase in each epoch'? I have just 2 data loaders (train and test).

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate test result in `test_epoch_end`:

```
def test_step(self, test_batch):
    x, y = test_batch
    logits = self.forward(x)
    loss = self.mean_squared_error_loss(logits.squeeze(-1), y.float())


    self.log('test_loss', loss)
    return {'test_loss': loss, "logits":logits, "labels": y}

def test_epoch_end(self, outputs):
    all_preds, all_labels = [], []
    for output in outputs:
        probs = list(output['logits'].cpu().detach().numpy()) # predicted values
        labels = list(output['labels'].flatten().cpu().detach().numpy())
        all_preds.extend(probs)
        all_labels.extend(labels)

    # you can calculate R2 here or save results as file
    r2 = ...
```

Note that this only works on a single GPU. If you are using multiple GPUs, you need some function to gather results from different GPUs.

To get model predictions, you need to add a predict_step() in the model class.

```
def predict_step(self, test_batch):
    x, y = test_batch
    logits = self.forward(x)
    return {'logits': logits, 'labels':y}
```

And run:

```
outputs = trainer.predict(model, test_loader, return_predictions=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. If I want to return `r2` or other metrics from `test_epoch_end` to the `train` function (as per the question) then how can I do it?

Comment: You can catch them by returning in `test_epoch_end()` (see updates).

Comment: I have tried but I am not getting the return values. The file is saving and has no errors. But, the saved file contains the value of `log` from `test_epoch_end()` function not from the return (df or list) from the function

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. I update the answer to use `trainer.predict()`.

Comment: @joe32140 Is there a way to get predictions as a batch-wise iterator, in case you can't fit everything in memory?

Comment: If you plan to write each batch to the disk, maybe saving logits/labels directly to the disk in the `predict_step` function can work?